# How to customize infoWindow (but without using google-maps-utility-library-v3)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to customize my infoWindow adding "border-radius" and "background-color", but in each similar question that I have searched here, the answer is to use **google-maps-utility-library-v3**...

I know that is a good solution, (infact for other reasons I use that), but I would like to know if is there another way to achieve what I want to do...

I tried in this way, with jquery:

```
var infoWindow;  //like global variable

var centrocircle= new google.maps.LatLng(X,Z);
    var circleOptions = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: colore,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: colore,
        fillOpacity: 0.85,
        map: map,                   
        center: centrocircle,
        info: '<p id="hook">home</p>',
        radius: raggio*770
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(circleOptions, 'domready', function() {
    var l = $('#hook').parent().parent().parent().siblings();
    for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        if($(l[i]).css('z-index') == 'auto') {
            $(l[i]).css('border-radius', '16px 16px 16px 16px');
            $(l[i]).css('border', '2px solid red');
        }
    }  
});

google.maps.event.addListener(circleOptions, 'click', function() {                  
    infoWindow.setPosition(this.center);
    infoWindow.setContent(this.info); 
    infoWindow.open(map,this);
})
```

but doesn't work....

I hope can you help me... thanks!

**EDIT**

```
var infoWindow;  //like global variable

var tooltipHTML = 
    '<div id="content" style="width:400px">'+
    '   <div id="infoWindow">'+
    '   </div>'+
    '   <h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">NAME           CUSTOMER</h2>'+
    '   <div id="bodyContent">'+
    '       <p>MORE INFO OF: <b>CUSTOMER</b></p>'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>';
```

And

```
var centrocircle= new google.maps.LatLng(X,Z);
var circleOptions = new google.maps.Circle({
   strokeColor: colore,
   strokeOpacity: 1,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: colore,
   fillOpacity: 0.85,
   map: map,     
   center: centrocircle,
   info: tooltipHTML,
   radius: raggio*770
});

google.maps.event.addListener(circleOptions, 'click', function() {     
   infoWindow.setPosition(this.center);
   infoWindow.setContent(this.info); 
   infoWindow.open(map,this);
})
```

Comment: I think you would need a infobox for that. Styling the infowindow itself is hideous task and you just end up seeing all your effort was waste of time the day google decides to do things a little bit different, and that day _will_ come, sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize de infowindow applying some CSS rules to the following class ".gm-style-iw". Recently I wrote a post explaining just that, you can read it here - [5 ways to customize Google Maps InfoWindow](http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html)

Comment: Yes, but what then `.gm-style-iw` is changed to `.gm-st-iw` or similar? And how to distinct properly between multiple infowindows?

Comment: @MigMar yes is a great solution, but i have only little problem... When i click on the marker (in my situation circle) it opens the infoWindow, but the map goes down for same pixel... Do you know what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: @davidkonrad that's a good point. That's why I'm forcing the usage of the version that is compatible with my code (?v=3.20 actual experimental version). Then I have 3 to 9 months to test new versions. This solution wasn't tested with multiple infowindows, may not be a right solution for that.

Comment: @MigMar, +1 fine work. Was trying something similar, but stopped when I realized It was hard to distinguish between infowindows, like one with red border, another with green border and so on. But nice styling of std. infowindows anyway! You should add a code example to your answer to attract more upvotes :)

Comment: @Mapsism Borja normally the map goes down because of the height of the infowindow. Do you have any online example?

Comment: @Mapsism Borja  to add color to tail you just have to add a background color to this line: iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'box-shadow': 'rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6) 0px 1px 6px', 'z-index' : '1', 'background-color' : 'blue'}); Please pay atention to what davidkonrad said, you have to track updates to the API to make sure this workaround will be fine in future updates.

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks, i think you can style different infowindows adding a class to .gm-style-iw depending of the type of the marker. For example markers of the type of Culture are blue and markers of Sport are red. For now this is just a theory, but you gave me a good idea for the next post update.

Comment: @MigMar to change the color of tail shadow ? i must to change box-shadow or background color? and line is same (when change only         **':nth-child(1)'**  ?

Comment: The tail shadow have two components, there is a front DIV with white color and it has a shadow. This shadow can be changed with the following line: 
iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'z-index' : '1', 'box-shadow' : 'rgba(10, 84, 199, 0.32) 0px 1px 6px'});
You must change box-shadow values.

Comment: The second DIV is bellow of the first DIV and you can change its color with the following line:
iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important; border-top-color: rgba(10, 84, 199, 0.0980392)'});
You must change border-top-color values.

I believe this second DIV is a shadow for some older browsers that don't support the box-shadow propriety.

Comment: Considering the comments on your blog post, people are still reading your tutorial and trying to use it. This is all UNDOCUMENTED and should NOT be used. You should delete your blog post as well as this answer as it is all very BAD practice. CSS class names, selectors, etc. are subject to change at any time without notice from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Better use a Tooltip:

Declare HTML structure as desired for it:

```
var tooltipHTML = 
    '<div id="content" style="width:400px">'+
    '   <div id="infoWindow">'+
    '   </div>'+
    '   <h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">NAME CUSTOMER</h2>'+
    '   <div id="bodyContent">'+
    '       <p>MORE INFO OF: <b>CUSTOMER</b></p>'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>';
```

You will need an empty infoWindow:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
```

Then insert the tooltip:

```
bindInfoWindow(circleOptions, map, infowindow, tooltipHTML);
```

`bindInfoWindow` function adds a listener to the element.

```
function bindInfoWindow(circle, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: Sometimes, there are problems with `Circle tooltip's`, so, if above code does not work, I've found [HERE](http://gotoanswer.com/?q=google%20map%2C%20show%20tooltip%20on%20a%20circle) a possible workaround with title attibute:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle,'mouseover',function(){
     this.getMap().getDiv().setAttribute('title',this.get('title'));});

google.maps.event.addListener(circle,'mouseout',function(){
     this.getMap().getDiv().removeAttribute('title');});
```

Comment: Jordi sorry for my ignorance, but where are style CSS for id in "tooltipHTML" ??

Comment: sure! you can use `style="color:red"` or define a `class="red"` as usual in your wiew and declare `.red` class in your `CSS stylesheet` .

Comment: Jordi see my EDIT.. it should work, what do yuo think?

Comment: It should, but after investigating a bit, there can be problems sometimes, check the workaround in the edit...

Comment: Jordi i tried but doesn't work with your code, i tried also add "tooltipHTML" to info (like can you see in my EDIT), but the style is also for infoWindow's content, not for all infoWindow :/

Comment: have you tried with workaround in my edit? maybe `this.getMap().getDiv().setAttribute('title' ,tooltipHTML);});` ??

Comment: did you check the link???? `The tooltip is created via the native title-attribute of DOM-elements, but the` **API doesn't provide any method to access the DOMElement that contains the circle**.

`A possible workaround may be to use the title-attribute of the map-div instead(set it onmouseover and remove it onmouseout)`

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry :( but i didn't understand where to insert event.addlistener (mouseover and out), i didn't understand why in new.google.maps.InfoWindow there {} , and now i didn't understand why "title"... Sorry Jordi :( thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which is still a hackish workaround and counts on the current hierarchy / implementation.

[image]

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonkatz/Lkmzzxge/4/)**

I used this to implement the content exactly as I liked, added my own arrow manually (with CSS) and just modified the location in order to line it up correctly with the marker on the map.

Main idea is to hide all the surrounding content and align manually to marker using the 'pixelOffset' property.

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(4, 20),
});

google.maps.event.addListener(displayedInfoWindow, 'domready', function() {
    var el = $('.gm-style-iw');
    el.siblings().css('visibility', 'hidden');
    el.click(function() {
        displayedInfoWindow.close();
    });
});

displayedInfoWindow.setContent(myHtmlContent);
displayedInfoWindow.open(myMapObj, marker);
```

Comment: This is as bad as @MigMar answer. Undocumented. Do not use.